# How to stop not responding tkinter whilst using pytube?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, pytube

I have created a tkinter application that downloads audio/video. It does work fine, however (guessing here) because the download takes 5-10 seconds it blocks the mainloop and causes it to say not responding for a bit until complete, which isnt very good. I know the use of threading is possible, but I've never really used that and all examples I've attempted haven't worked properly.

Here is my FULL code, without threading: (I will show just certain features if that is too long to read through, which it probably is

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from pytube import YouTube
import sys, os, threading, time

def btn_clicked():
    print("Button Clicked")


window = Tk()

window.geometry("505x187")
window.title("Youtube Video Downloader")
photo = PhotoImage(file = "icon.png")
window.iconphoto(False, photo)
window.configure(bg = "#3d3d3d")
canvas = Canvas(
    window,
    bg = "#3d3d3d",
    height = 187,
    width = 505,
    bd = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    relief = "ridge")
canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)



def round_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, radius=25, **kwargs):
        
    points = [x1+radius, y1,
              x1+radius, y1,
              x2-radius, y1,
              x2-radius, y1,
              x2, y1,
              x2, y1+radius,
              x2, y1+radius,
              x2, y2-radius,
              x2, y2-radius,
              x2, y2,
              x2-radius, y2,
              x2-radius, y2,
              x1+radius, y2,
              x1+radius, y2,
              x1, y2,
              x1, y2-radius,
              x1, y2-radius,
              x1, y1+radius,
              x1, y1+radius,
              x1, y1]

    return canvas.create_polygon(points, **kwargs, smooth=True)

radius = 10
olw = 1
ft = None

ebl = []
eb = round_rectangle(
    320, 37, 320+174, 37+51,
    fill = "#212121",
    radius = radius,
    outline = "")
ebl.append(eb)

dl = []
d = round_rectangle(
    320, 135, 320+174, 135+43,
    fill = "#212121",
    radius = radius,
    outline = "")
dl.append(d)

dt = canvas.create_text(
    370, 148,
    text = "DOWNLOAD",
    fill = "#a0a0a0",
    anchor = "nw",
    font = ("None", int(14.0) - 5))
dl.append(dt)

mptl = []
mpt = round_rectangle(
    320, 97, 320+82, 97+31,
    fill = "#212121",
    radius = radius,
    outline = "")
mptl.append(mpt)

mpfl = []
mpf = round_rectangle(
    412, 97, 412+82, 97+31,
    fill = "#212121",
    radius = radius,
    outline = "")
mpfl.append(mpf)

pb = my_rectangle = round_rectangle(
    11, 10, 11+300, 10+168,
    fill = "#212121",
    radius = radius,
    outline = "")

ebt = canvas.create_text(
    326, 43,
    text = "Video URL:",
    fill = "#a0a0a0",
    anchor = "nw",
    font = ("None", int(13.0) - 5))
ebl.append(ebt)

mptt = canvas.create_text(
    348, 103,
    text = "MP3",
    fill = "#a0a0a0",
    anchor = "nw",
    font = ("None", int(14.0) - 5))
mptl.append(mptt)

mpft = canvas.create_text(
    440, 103,
    text = "MP4",
    fill = "#a0a0a0",
    anchor = "nw",
    font = ("None", int(14.0) - 5))
mpfl.append(mpft)

canvas.create_text(
    320, 13,
    text = "Youtube Video Downloader",
    fill = "#a0a0a0",
    anchor = "nw",
    font = ("None", int(15.0) - 5))

entry0_img = PhotoImage(file = f"img_textBox0.png")
entry0_bg = canvas.create_image(
    406.0, 70.5,
    image = entry0_img)

ebf = Entry(
    bd = 0,
    bg = "#212121",
    fg = "#727272",
    insertbackground = "#727272",
    highlightthickness = 0)

ebf.place(
    x = 326, y = 61,
    width = 160,
    height = 17)


def OnHover(item):
    if item in mptl or mpfl:
        if canvas.itemcget(item, "outline") == "":
            if canvas.itemcget(item, "tag") == "clickset":
                pass
            else:
                canvas.itemconfig(item, outline="#FF7276", width = olw, tag="hoverset")
        else:
            pass

def UnHover(item):
    if item in mptl or mpfl:
        if canvas.itemcget(item, "tag") == "hoverset":
            canvas.itemconfig(item, outline="", width = olw, tag="")
        else:
            pass
def bindhover(l, item):
    for i in l:
        canvas.tag_bind(i, '<Enter>', lambda event: OnHover(item=item))
        canvas.tag_bind(i, '<Leave>', lambda event: UnHover(item=item))

bindhover(mptl, mpt)
bindhover(mpfl, mpf)
bindhover(dl, d)


def OnClick(item):
    global ft
    if item in mptl or mpfl:
        if canvas.itemcget(item, "tag") == "hoverset":
            if item == mpt:
                if canvas.itemcget(mpf, "outline") == "":
                    ft = "mp3"
                else:
                    canvas.itemconfig(mpf, outline="")
                    ft = "mp3"
            if item == mpf:
                if canvas.itemcget(mpt, "outline") == "":
                    ft = "mp4"
                else:
                    canvas.itemconfig(mpt, outline="")
                    ft = "mp4"

            canvas.itemconfig(item, tag="clickset")
        else:
            pass
def bindclick(l, item):
    for i in l:
        canvas.tag_bind(i, '<Button-1>', lambda event: OnClick(item=item))
        
bindclick(mptl, mpt)
bindclick(mpfl, mpf)

def download():
    e = False

    link = ebf.get()
    try:
        link2 = YouTube(link)
    except:
        messagebox.showinfo("Invalid link", "Invalid youtube link")
        e = True
    if e == False:
        if ft == None:
            messagebox.showinfo("Select a file type", "No file type has been selected")
            e = True
        elif ft == 'mp3':
            if e == False:
                video = link2.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
                vid = video.download('Downloads')
                print("test")
                base, ext = os.path.splitext(vid)
                new_file = base + '.mp3'
                os.rename(vid, new_file)
        else:
            if e == False:
                video = link2.streams.first()
                vid = video.download('Downloads')
            
        else:
            pass
def bdownload(l, item):
    for i in l:
        canvas.tag_bind(i, '<Button-1>', lambda event: download())    
bdownload(dl, d)

window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()
```

Download:

```
def download():
    e = False

    link = ebf.get()
    try:
        link2 = YouTube(link)
    except:
        messagebox.showinfo("Invalid link", "Invalid youtube link")
        e = True
    if e == False:
        if ft == None:
            messagebox.showinfo("Select a file type", "No file type has been selected")
            e = True
        elif ft == 'mp3':
            if e == False:
                video = link2.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
                vid = video.download('Downloads')
                print("test")
                base, ext = os.path.splitext(vid)
                new_file = base + '.mp3'
                os.rename(vid, new_file)
        else:
            if e == False:
                video = link2.streams.first()
                vid = video.download('Downloads')
            
        else:
            pass
def bdownload(l, item):
    for i in l:
        canvas.tag_bind(i, '<Button-1>', lambda event: download())    
bdownload(dl, d)
```

Just wondering how to put that in a thread?

Comment: @TheLizzard  I thought I might have. Though I did say I thought that was what was happening, I was just wondering how I'd put it in a thread since I'm not great at threading and no guides have helped or worked.

Comment: Basically you create a thread using: `new_thread = threading.Thread(target=<the function that needs to be in the new thread>, daemon=True, args=<a tuple of the args that you want to pass into the function>)` then you can just call `new_thread.start()`

Comment: @TheLizzard  Thankyou! Is there a way to terminate it when it is done, and can it be run again?

Comment: You can't rerun the thread but you can create another one. When the function called ends, the thread will be automatically terminated

Comment: @TheLizzard How would I do that? I thought that aswell, but for me it looped? Sorry, quite new to this.

Comment: I don't know much about `pytube`. Which part of your code actually downloads the file? If you tell me that, I should be able to write an answer.

Comment: @TheLizzard The last bit of my post there is a seperate bit of code, this is the download function.

Comment: More specifically is it the `video.download("Downloads")` line?

Comment: Yes, it is that.

Comment: @TheLizzard forgot to mention you, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format to starting a new thread is:

```py
new_thread = threading.Thread(target=..., daemon=True, args=(..., ...))
new_thread.start()
```

So try this:

```py
def download_worker(player, ft):
    vid = video.download('Downloads')
    if ft == "mp3":
        print("test")
        base, ext = os.path.splitext(vid)
        new_file = base + '.mp3'
        os.rename(vid, new_file)

def download():
    ...
    elif ft == 'mp3':
        if e == False:
            video = link2.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
            # Imagine this like: download_worker(video, ft)
            new_thread = threading.Thread(target=download_worker, daemon=True, args=(video, ft))
            new_thread.start()
    else:
        if e == False:
            video = link2.streams.first()
            # Imagine this like: download_worker(video, ft)
            new_thread = threading.Thread(target=download_worker, daemon=True, args=(video, ft))
            new_thread.start()
     # Keep in mind that the `vid` variable doesn't exist here.
```

In this case, the target function is `download_worker` and the arguments are: `video` and `ft`.

The thread automatically ends when the target function ends.